# Support both pan&zoom and brush operations in force directed graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my app I would like to support both `pan&zoom` operations but also be able to switch to `brush` operations. During the `pan&zoom` operations I am able to click on a node and move it in the graph using `drag` operations. I am also able to handle `mouse` events successfully.

When I switch to `brush` operations it seems that I cannot `drag` nodes any more.  When I move the cursor over a node, nothing happens even though I have `mouse` events defined on that node. On the bright side I can select multiple nodes using the `brush` and I can move them with the arrow keys.

My problem is that I would like to be able to move the selected nodes (while in `brush` mode) with the mouse in addition to the arrow keys. Handling `mouse` events would also be nice.

I have created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/vrdqonf2/2/ that demonstrates my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are appending the group element for brush after the svg which contains the force directed graph. In this case, the target of mouse events will be the brush always since the nodes lies underneath that element.

```
test.brush = test.svg //Append the brush first
    .append("g")
    .datum( function() { return { selected: false, previouslySelected: false }; } )
    .attr( "class", "brush" );

test.container = test.svg  //Now append the svg for graph
    .append( "svg:svg" )
    .attr( "width", chartWidth)
    .attr( "height", chartHeight)
    .style( "outline", "1px solid red" )
    .append( "svg:g" )
    .attr( "transform", "translate(" + test.translate + ") scale(" + test.scale + ")" );
```

**Update**

Update the else part in `toggleBrushing` method also as shown below since you are appending the brush after svg in toggleBrushing method too. You will have to prepend the brush before svg. You can refer more about `insert` method [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections). Here is the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrdqonf2/4/)

```
-------------
-------------
else
{
    ---------------------
    ---------------------       
    test.brush = test.svg
        .insert("g","svg") //Use insert instead of append 
        .datum( function() { return { selected: false, previouslySelected: false }; } )
        .attr( "class", "brush" );

    ---------------------
    ---------------------
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realize order was important.

Comment: it seems that if I toggle from pan/zoom mode to brush mode and then back to pan/zoom and then again back to brush mode, I am not able to move nodes again. So moving nodes in brush mode works only the first time.

Comment: Yes you are right.. this happens because you are appending the brush after svg in `toggleBrushing` method too. Please see my updated answer.